# What is wrong with my binary search tree insertion logic?

Tags: c++

binarysearch.h :

```
    #ifndef BST_BINARYSEARCH_H
    #define BST_BINARYSEARCH_H

    struct Node{
        int value;
        Node* left;
        Node* right;
    };

    class BST{
    public:
        Node* root;
        BST(){
            root = nullptr;
        }
        Node* insertNode(Node* root, Node toInsert);
        void inOrder(Node* root);
    };

    #endif //BST_BINARYSEARCH_H
```

binarysearch.cpp :

```
    #include 
    #include 
    #include "binarysearch.h"

    Node* BST::insertNode(Node* root, Node toInsert) {
        if(root == nullptr){
            root = &toInsert;
        }
        else {
            if (toInsert.value value)
                root->left = insertNode(root->left, toInsert);
            else
                root->right = insertNode(root->right, toInsert);
        }
        return root;
    }

    void BST::inOrder(Node *root) {
        if(root!= NULL){
            inOrder(root->left);
            std::coutvalue;
            inOrder(root->right);
        }
    }
```

main.cpp:

```
    #include 
    #include "binarysearch.h"

    int main() {

        BST bst;
        Node* root = nullptr;

        Node a;
        a.value = 4;
        a.left = NULL;
        a.right = NULL;

        root = bst.insertNode(root, a);
        bst.insertNode(root, a);
        a.value = 5;
        bst.insertNode(root, a);
        a.value = 6;
        bst.insertNode(root, a);
        a.value = 7;
        bst.insertNode(root, a);
        a.value = 8;
        bst.insertNode(root, a);

        bst.inOrder(root);
        return 0;
    }
```

Apparently my root keeps moving from the original position as I insert more items.

I am getting Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV) on bst.inOrder(root).

What is the issue here?

Comment: Your program has undefined behavior.  The reason is because of the way you are using pointers.  A tree needs to allocate its own memory to persist storage, or that memory needs to be allocated _and persist_ for the duration of the tree's lifetime.  In your program, neither of these things are true.

Comment: Instead, what you're doing is taking the address of a value passed in as an argument and storing that.  The arguments live only on the stack.  Once the `insertNode` function returns, any pointer into that stack must not be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the insert node function, here you say if the tree is empty, we set the root to be the address of "toInsert". The problem here is toInsert isn't a reference, it's passed by copy. Which means toInsert is a temporary local copy variable, which expires as soon as the function ends. Meaning your root pointer now doesn't point to anything.

```
   //NOTE: Passing toInsert, copy is made
   Node* BST::insertNode(Node* root, Node toInsert) {
        //NOTE: root is null, so we set it to point to the node's copy
        if(root == nullptr){
            root = &toInsert;
        }
      //NOTE: The copy is destroyed because we ran out of scope
    }
```

Solution would be to make "toInsert" a pointer, or a reference